# verify element padding using Galen Framework

Tags: automated-testing, selenium, testng

I am in process of evaluating [Galen](http://galenframework.com/) as UI automation framework. I am blocked at one point where Galen is unable to give correct results in case of padding around an element. This is the sample DOM.

```html
<html>
 <body>
  <div id="div1" style="background-color: yellow; height:200px; width:500px">
   <div id="div2" style="padding-left:15px; padding-right:15px; background-color: red; height:100px;">
    <h2>TEST CONTENT</h2>
   </div>
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

My spec file reads as below

```
@objects
    div1    //div[@id="div1"]
    div2    //div[@id="div2"]/h2

= Personal Tab =
    @on desktop
        div2:
            inside div1 15px left right
```

On running the test the failure message reads something like below

```
div2 is 0px right instead of 15px
```

I read one of the posts which suggested to use CSS properties using selenium. I do not want to use this method. Instead if there is anything provided by Galen would be useful

Any clues what can be alternative to solve the puzzle ?

Comment: got this resolved. It was my misunderstanding about css padding/border/margin concepts. Apologies for the noise and Thanks everyone for your help

Comment: Can you post your answer?

Answer (score 2):

Since the padding is the space inside div. When the rendered look like

[image]

According to the sample HTML, I'd write my test to verify

- There are three objects; *div1*, *div2* and *h2*. In your code, you define *div2* object name to *h2* actual object. It's confuse.
- *div2* is fit inside *div1*, the top left right is 0px.
- *h2* is inside *div2*, the left is 15px. The right is apparently not 15px, I might not put it to the script. If you want to, you can do a math.

Therefore the code will be:

```
@objects
div1    //div[@id="div1"]
div2    //div[@id="div2"]
h2      //div[@id="div2"]/h2

= Personal Tab =
    @on desktop
        div2:
            inside div1 0px left right, 0px top
        h2:
            inside div2 15px left
```

I don't have Galen installed to verify my answer but I think it could help. :) Good luck.

Comment: you can also try to refactor this stuff to a custom rule: http://galenframework.com/docs/reference-galen-spec-language-guide/#CustomRules